# Floating Action Button in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, floating-action-button

I had completed my App's home page in Xamarin.Forms Portable.

Now i want to add a Flotation Action Button In my Android Project !

Is there any way to add FAB for Android in my existing home page, which was coded in Xamarin.Forms Portable.

OR

I want to create a separate home page for Android and add call it as a MainPage for android ?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: It depends on what you want exactly. Do you want it only in your Android project? Or also in your other apps? Do you even have other apps? If you do, and just want it in your Android project, you probably want a `CustomRenderer`. Also have a look at this; https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/fab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the official support library came out I ported the FAB over.

There is now a Xamarin.Forms sample in my GitHub repo that you can use: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android

Comment: Now that the official support library has been released and you have deprected your github library, how should we implement a FAB?

Comment: I would be interested in that too. Could you add an update for the year 2017?

Answer (score 4):

Build a Custom Control
For the FAB's properties to be bindable in Xamarin.Forms, we need a custom control with bindable properties.

```
public class FloatingActionButtonView : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create<FloatingActionButtonView,string>( p => p.ImageName, string.Empty);
    public string ImageName 
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue (ImageNameProperty); } 
      set { SetValue (ImageNameProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorNormalProperty = BindableProperty.Create<FloatingActionButtonView,Color>( p => p.ColorNormal, Color.White);
    public Color ColorNormal 
    {
      get { return (Color)GetValue (ColorNormalProperty); } 
      set { SetValue (ColorNormalProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorPressedProperty = BindableProperty.Create<FloatingActionButtonView,Color>( p => p.ColorPressed, Color.White);
    public Color ColorPressed 
    {
      get { return (Color)GetValue (ColorPressedProperty); } 
      set { SetValue (ColorPressedProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorRippleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<FloatingActionButtonView,Color>( p => p.ColorRipple, Color.White);
    public Color ColorRipple 
    {
      get { return (Color)GetValue (ColorRippleProperty); } 
      set { SetValue (ColorRippleProperty, value); } 
    }
    ...
}
```

We will then map each property to a corresponding property on the native FAB control.

**Attach a Renderer**

If we want to use a native control in Xamarin.Forms, we need a renderer. For simplicity, lets use a `ViewRenderer`. This renderer will map our custom `FloatingActionButtonView` to an `Android.Widget.FrameLayout`.

```
public class FloatingActionButtonViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<FloatingActionButtonView, FrameLayout>
{
    ...
    private readonly Android.Content.Context context;
    private readonly FloatingActionButton fab;

    public FloatingActionButtonViewRenderer()
    {
        context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FloatingActionButtonView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        if (e.OldElement != null)
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= HandlePropertyChanged;

        if (this.Element != null) {
            //UpdateContent ();
            this.Element.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
        }

        Element.Show = Show;
        Element.Hide = Hide;

        SetFabImage(Element.ImageName);

        fab.ColorNormal = Element.ColorNormal.ToAndroid();
        fab.ColorPressed = Element.ColorPressed.ToAndroid();
        fab.ColorRipple = Element.ColorRipple.ToAndroid();

        var frame = new FrameLayout(Forms.Context);
        frame.RemoveAllViews();
        frame.AddView(fab);

        SetNativeControl (frame);
    }

    public void Show(bool animate = true)
    {
        fab.Show(animate);
    }

    public void Hide(bool animate = true)
    {
        fab.Hide(animate);
    }

    void HandlePropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Content") {
            Tracker.UpdateLayout ();
        } 
        else if (e.PropertyName == FloatingActionButtonView.ColorNormalProperty.PropertyName) 
        {
            fab.ColorNormal = Element.ColorNormal.ToAndroid();
        } 
        else if (e.PropertyName == FloatingActionButtonView.ColorPressedProperty.PropertyName) 
        {
            fab.ColorPressed = Element.ColorPressed.ToAndroid();
        } 
        else if (e.PropertyName == FloatingActionButtonView.ColorRippleProperty.PropertyName) 
        {
            fab.ColorRipple = Element.ColorRipple.ToAndroid();
        }
        ...
    }

    void SetFabImage(string imageName)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageName))
        {
            try
            {
                var drawableNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageName);
                var resources = context.Resources;
                var imageResourceName = resources.GetIdentifier(drawableNameWithoutExtension, "drawable", context.PackageName);
                fab.SetImageBitmap(Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, imageResourceName));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("There was no Android Drawable by that name.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Pull it all Together**

OK! We've built the custom control, and mapped it to a renderer. The last step is laying out the control in our view.

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        var fab = new FloatingActionButtonView() {
            ImageName = "ic_add.png",
            ColorNormal = Color.FromHex("ff3498db"),
            ColorPressed = Color.Black,
            ColorRipple = Color.FromHex("ff3498db")
        };

        // Main page layout
        var pageLayout = new StackLayout {
            Children = 
            {
                new Label {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
                }
            }};

        var absolute = new AbsoluteLayout() { 
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, 
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };

        // Position the pageLayout to fill the entire screen.
        // Manage positioning of child elements on the page by editing the pageLayout.
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(pageLayout, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(pageLayout, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
        absolute.Children.Add(pageLayout);

        // Overlay the FAB in the bottom-right corner
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(fab, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(fab, new Rectangle(1f, 1f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
        absolute.Children.Add(fab);

        Content = absolute;
    }
}
```

Complete code on Github : [Floating Action Button Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/chrisriesgo/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android/tree/master/xamarin.forms/FabSampleForms)

Comment: Visual Studio tells me that the generic version of BindableProperty.Create is obsolete and will be removed. How would you solve it the current correct way?

Comment: @zuckerthoben you have to change the BindableProperty.Create<TDeclarer, TPropertyType>() to:
`public static readonly BindableProperty TheProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "ThePropertyName", returnType: typeof ("string/Color etc.."),
                declaringType: typeof ("ClassName"), defaultValue: "Default value");`

Comment: Is this now obsolete since the official Support libraries are there?